# Android studio clean error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

So I'm using Android studio for my android app and after adding a .jar file to my project I now get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':androidrss:processDebugTestManifest'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4 declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0

Thing is that I can build and run my app but i cannot do a clean of my project (Build->Clean Project). So i tried removing the .jar file and then do a clean still gets the same error. Also did a File->Invalidate Caches/Restart, this didn't work either.

I tired searching my project for `minSdkVersion 1` and `minSdkVersion "1"` without any hits.

This is my Manifest.XML part with SDK version:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

This is my Grandle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.golfboxdk"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':androidrss')
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.25.5-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/axis-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/bugsense3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/diting-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/pojoxml-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

So anyone able to help me out with this clean error?

EDIT 1: I took a look at the manifestMerge file thats generated when the error occurs and is has minSdkVersion="1", But why is this? Been struggling with this for 3 hours now, would really appreciate some help.

EDIT 2: It seems like setting the min/max SDK for ALL of my modules did the trick.

Comment: You must go to the build.gradle file within you "mobile" folder and change there the min sdk.

Comment: I'm on a mac, is it still a folder named "mobile" i need to look for?